# Import from Excel into DataTable without using OleDbConnection or for loops

Tags: c#, excel, import

I would like to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet to get the data from Excel; Would it be possible to put all the data inside a worksheet into a DataTable without using for loops or OleDbConnection?

I have found this solution from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244971/how-do-i-import-from-excel-to-a-dataset-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel) but the performance gets affected if there is a large set of data in the Excel sheet:

```
public DataTable Import(String path)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;

    int index = 0;
    object rowIndex = 2;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Mobile");
    dt.Columns.Add("Landline");
    dt.Columns.Add("Email");
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");

    DataRow row;

    while (((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1]).Value2 != null)
    {
        rowIndex = 2 + index;
        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1]).Value2);
        row[1] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 2]).Value2);
        row[2] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 3]).Value2);
        row[3] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 4]).Value2);
        row[4] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 5]).Value2);
        index++;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    app.Workbooks.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: It's not the loop that's slow, it's the reading of individual cells within the loop. [get the whole range in one go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4327081/445425)

Comment: Thank you Chris. I've just implemented what you said and it is indeed much faster. Please add answer to this question so I could mark it as answered.